# Adding heading to existing control

Tags: wpf, controls

I want to create a custom control type that behaves exactly like a `ListBox`, except that it displays with a heading above it.

I think what I need to do is inherit from `ListBox` and use code like the following:

```
var originalTree = Template.VisualTree;

var panel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));

var heading = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
heading.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Heading");

panel.AppendChild(heading);
panel.AppendChild(originalTree);

Template.VisualTree = panel;
```

Except wherever I tried to place it, it didn't work, because `Template.VisualTree` was `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain why you downvoted this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know templates can be defined in various ways, if the `VisualTree` is `null`, it has been generated 'by reference', in that case it has been set with [`Frameworktemplate.Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.template.aspx).

(*Editing that is **not** intended, all members are internal or private*)

I would use a UserControl if you are going to take the whole root anyway.

---

**Edit:** Copying and editing the default template should be fine as well, here is the default style:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#828790"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

(You could bind the header `TextBox.Text` to the `ListBox.Tag` then you do not need to subclass it)

Default templates and styles are [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx).

Comment: I don't want to use `UserControl`, because I want to use all the existing functionality of `ListBox`, including its template.

Comment: You can use all the existing functionality, you just need to propagate all the properties, events & methods. Well, those are quite a lot, so you could also expose the internal ListBox, which means that your paths get a bit longer.

Comment: Which is exactly why I think it would be much cleaner if I just inherited the `ListBox`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the `Template` property is set. So how do I use it?

Comment: It's not really cleaner to inherit from ListBox, controls in WPF are defined by their functionality, not their appearance, while having a header could count as functionality it's not something one should hard code into a *specialized* control. Also, about using the `Template` property: You better forget about that, it's all encapsulated (all members private or internal), you are not supposed to mess with it. Just copy the default template and modify it.

Comment: And how do I copy and modify the default template?

Answer (score 0):

This article http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html implies that a UserControl is a conglomerate of several controls - in your case a Label or TextBlock plus a ListBox? So is a user control a possible solution?